# The use of 'totter' in this context

Tags: verb-usage

> "Smooth," said Ron approvingly, as the waiters popped up on all sides, some bearing silver trays of pumpkin juice, Butterbeer and Firewhisky, others **tottering piles of tarts and sandwiches**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I know 'totter' is an intransitive verb, but here it seems to be used as a transitive verb. I'm confused. Can it be transitive in any case?

Comment: 'Tottering' is an adjective in that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "*totter*" means to move in an unsteady way; "tottering" is the gerund or present participle. As you may know, the present participle form of a verb can become an *adjective*.

So, "tottering" in your example means that the piles of food were perhaps so high that they were swaying from side to side. The piles *were tottering*.

Comment: Does the phrase omit 'bearing'? *others bearing tottering piles of tarts and sandwiches*

Comment: @dan There is no need to re-use the word. It has been established that the trays are bearing different items, and what follows is like a list. An example for contrast: "*One girl was wearing a blue dress, the other a red one*". There is no need to re-use the words "wearing" or "dress".